# Product of two analytic spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, ringed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be two analytic spaces. Does the product $X\times Y$ exist? (in the category of analytic spaces and the category of locally ringed spaces)

I try to mimic the proof of schemes. We can do it locally, so can assume both affine. But for schemes we can do it because affine schemes and rings are equivalent categories so we can construct the product via tensor product of rings. So how to do this for analytic spaces?

Any hint or reference would be helpful.

Comment: If one is working with complex-analytic spaces, a proof is worked out across sections 3.2-3.4 of Chapter 1 of the book "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" by Grauert-Remmert, with the theorem appearing on page 27.

Comment: @msteve thanks, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @msteve one more question: how about the product in the category of locally ringed spaces?